# Display SQL Polygon on a map in Kusto

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-explorer, kql

I've imported SQL data into Azure Data Explorer that contains a column that is of type SQL Polygon.  Is there a way to display these polygons on a map in Kusto?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your example as a datatable()?

Comment: Hi Patrick, currently we don't visualize polygons. This is in our roadmap, however there is no specific ETA. 
Please post your idea at [https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/a952add5-eb24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0]. This will help us with prioritization.

Also, in order to work with Polygons in Kusto, you should use GeoJSON format, in dynamic type.

Here are currently supported geospatial visialization:

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tutorials/create-geospatial-visualizations

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/geospatial-visualizations

Comment: Hi @MichaelBrichko thank you.  The SQL table above has that well known format GeoJson.  I imported it into Kusto from SQL, but how do I work with this in Kusto?  How do I convert it into a dynamic?  I've tried a million ways

Comment: Please use parse_json() function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction).